# How to load value and display in ddslick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the jQuery plugin [`ddslick`](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) to display a drop down menu with images.

When I submit the form, the value that is set within this array is also sent along with the form.

```
var ddData = [{
    text: "sometext",
    value: 1,
    description: "something",
    imageSrc: "img/do.png"
}]
```

This is how I initialize the drop down menu:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $('#dropdownBasico' + i).ddslick({
            data: ddData,
            width: 150,
            imagePosition: "left",
            selectText: "How r u ?",
            onSelected: function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When the page is refreshed, I want the drop down to re-select the value that I previously submitted.
I got this working with a normal select and using a database query response `$data`.

```
echo "<select name='x_variablename' id='x_variablename' ><option value='".$data->variablename->EditValue."'>".$data->variablename->EditValue."</option>";
echo "<option value='1'>True</option>";
echo "<option value='0'>False</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

How can I use code to change the selected value with ddslick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the documentation on [`ddSlick`](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick).

Example:

`$('#dropdownBasico0').ddslick('select', {index: 2});`

This will select the third item within the first drop down menu.

Comment: That sound very promising, so I will need to do a compare command in js first, to check which value is saved there in database, then set display value accordingly. But after that, will the user still be able to select from menu ?